# GWT.create([AnyService.class]) hangs on hosted mode

Tags: java, gwt

I've been working on a project for more than eight months using GWT without any issue, recently I upgraded to version 2.1 and since then anytime I call GWT.create([AnyService].class) the browser hangs. It used to show me an OutOfMemoryException so I set Xmx to 4096m, XX:MaxPermSize to 1024m and -Xss to 1024k (I know is a lot but otherwise I get the OOME), since then the OOME stoped showing but the page never shows, nothing shows on the server log, nor on the GWT console.

I though the issue might be related to the browser, so I've tried using IE, FF, Safari and Chrome, and the same behavior is shown on all of them. This issue happens to me as well when working on Mac OS (snow leopard), and using Windows 7.

If I run the site in web mode then everything works ok, the thing is that debugging becomes impossible since the project currently has more than 30 modules, so compiling everything is not an option (takes something more than 30 minutes to compile all of them).

I'm using Maven with the plugin version 2.1.0-1, and I've tried with gwt libs 2.1.0 and 2.1.1 and none of them works for me. I also found some other posts from people reporting similar issues and there seems not to be a solution so far. I'm working from the console using maven (mvn gwt:run), not using any plugin like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Can anyone give me a clue on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

After 70+ hours working on this issue, I found what is causing it!, on my mac I'm using JVM 64 bits, the same on that windows 7 machine using an core i5 processor. After desperate tests I took my wife's computer running windows 7 and the project runs ok there, the only difference I could find after a while looking was the JVM version, it has 32 bits, so I downloaded the jvm 32 bits and installed it on my windows 7 machine instead of the 64 bits, and it worked smoothly...

what's the process for reporting an issue to the gwt team?, I think this clearly is one!

anyway, thank you for those who took the time to read on the issue, although no answers were provided!

Oscar H

Comment: Thanks for reporting back your findings.  It will a big help to any others that experience a similar issue in the future.  Hopefully SO will be able to help more on your future questions.

Comment: One more thing, on my Mac what I had to do is to set the <extraJvmArgs> tag inside the gwt-maven-plugin configuration with -d32 and -Xmx1024m, it made the trick... the only question that remains on my head is, what changed so that I required to make this configuration since everything had been working fine before?, anyway I've gotta say I feel a huge relief